# IOS Search bar SQlite - is it possible to search for both text and numbers in a database

Tags: ios, xcode

I am a newbie so please bear with me. I have tried searching for an answer to this but havent been successful.

I have an app that is doing a search on a sqlite database for colours. Its working ok for text search currently.

But in this database there are both names and numbers that represent each colour.

Currently the search is a text search and will look up the words but if i type in the numbers it wont find anything.

Is it possible to have a single search field that can look up both the text and numbers? Is there a tutorial on this? Or anyone offer any advice on how to set up the search to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you targeting a specific field (name) in the SQLite database that you are tying the search to?

If so you could set to search up to query the two fields (number and name) and return all results.  If there were duplicates then filter them out before displaying.

Comment: NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"color CONTAINS[cd] %@",theSearchBar.text];
        tableArray= (NSMutableArray*)[APP.threads filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

Comment: Is this the bit I might need to change? what would i separate the column references with?

Comment: I can change "color" to "colour_code" and it will search numbers only, I am just not sure how I can search both lists? thanks for your help

Comment: @Pip from the code you have provided you need to add is a 'OR' between the two things your are searching e.g. `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"color CONTAINS[cd] %@ OR colour_code CONTAINS[cd]",theSearchBar.text,theSearchBar.text];`

Answer (score 0):

From the answer provided by rossei i gess you are using CoreData for any query on your SQL database but as you didn't mentioned it in your question it is good to know that you can make a query directly to your SQLite DB without predicate in that case you can have a SQLQuery that check for both a string and a number:

```
select * from yourtable where yourtable.stringfield == "yourstring" and yourtable.numberfield == number
```